# Bootstrap4 Jumbotron Text and Button elements not scaling to Fit in Smaller View Screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm using Bootstrap 4's Jumbotron to style a landing page. Inside the jumbotron I have the standard headings and paragraphs with 2 call to action buttons. I have wrapped these elements in a div to position them correctly for a desktop screen. however when I shrink the window, the elements fall out of the jumbotron and mess up the look of the page.

Here is how it looks on desktop

[image]
And Here is how it looks on "mobile"

[image]
I hope you can see what I mean from the images. The background image of the jumbotron is perfectly responsive but the contents (text, buttons) are overflowing down the page.

Here is the relevant html

```
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="jumboContents"> 
          <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Other Mother!</h1>
          <p class="lead">Scroll Down To See Whats On Offer</p>
          <hr class="my-4">
          <p>Click Below To Start Shopping or Make a Request Instantly</p>
          <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Shop Now</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="contactBtn" href="#" role="button">Contact OM</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And Here is the relevant CSS

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    top: -170px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(images/homepg.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    z-index: -1;
}

.jumboContents {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to either wrap these styles in a media query, or use the built-in positioning classes, which are breakpoint-aware (they are wrapped in media queries for the various breakpoints defined by Bootstrap).

Comment: @TiesonT. thanks. That should have been obvious really. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the bootstrap grid classes on your divs to let them stack properly when shrunken screen. (ex: div class="col-md-4 col-sm-1")

Comment: Is it possible to use the grid system to divide a single div (or jumbotron) into rows and columns rather than the entire page?

Comment: So with the grid system you can divide up content within a single div. so say you have a single div across and it covers all 12 columns, then when you add those classes to the div, it will stack based upon what classes you applied to the div. I don't know how familiar you are with the grid system. here is a good view of it:  https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/ The whole idea of the grid system is to enable stacking when screensize shrinks. Now I do not know for a fact if a jumbotron can stack also, but never hurts to try. :)

Comment: I do not think it will be a problem with the jumbotron though. :) I'm sure you can apply those classes.